# Laravel route including all $_GET params

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.3 and I have named all my routes.

I want to use the route() function and include my $_GET params.

This is what I've tried :

```
<a href="{{ route('myRoute', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => str_slug($name)], request()->all()]) }}">
```

Or

```
<a href="{{ route('myRoute', [array_merge(['id' => $id, 'slug' => str_slug($name)], request()->all())]) }}">
```

For now, I got this error

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 377: Array to string
>   conversion (View: ....

Is there a way to include all params ? I don't want to list them one by one. Thanks

**EDIT**

I had en error in my code, now it works with :

```
<a href="{{ route('myRoute', array_merge(['id' => $id, 'slug' => str_slug($name)], request()->all())) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

`request()->all()` and `['id' => $id, 'slug' => str_slug($name)]` are arrays and you're trying to pass it as string. When you have a lot of data, it's better to pass it using `POST` method.

Comment: I've got an error in my code, I used `[ array_merge( ... ) ]`, I've created an array of array.. it works now. I know for POST ... but you sure that if I am talking about routes, I use GET params.

Answer (score 0):

A cheap hack would be this:

```
<a href="{{ route('myRoute') . '?' . http_build_query(array_merge(['id' => $id, 'slug' => str_slug($name)], request()->all())) }}">
```

[http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) turns an associative array into GET paramaters string (without the starting ?).